# Find certificate file expiration with powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate

I know how to do this normally, but the problem is all of the certs in question are not installed on my local machine.  I have a source control directory where they all sit, and I need to iterate over them with powershell to find which have expired.  There's too many to just double click on to view the "Valid from" information, so how can I get that using powershell?

Comment: Are they public,  digicert has a free notification system

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/16/use-powershell-and-net-to-find-expired-certificates.aspx

Comment: Check out openssl it has a load of functions that can probably do that for you

Comment: OpenSSL? Really? There is no need in OpenSSL, when PowerShell does this natively. Especially when the talk is about Windows platform.

Answer (score 3):

I was playing with certificates and came across this, I wasn't able to get the above code to work but I modified it to use GCI and filter and it worked, thanks !

```
gci C:\Users\myname\Documents\OT -Filter *.cer | 
%{
    $cert = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_.FullName
    if ($cert.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date)) {
        Write-Warning "$_ is expired"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are stored in files, then you can instantiate an `X509Certificate2` object from file and then check expiration date as usually:

```
dir c:\certs -Include *.cer, *.crt | %{
    $cert = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_.FullName
    if ($cert.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date)) {
        Write-Warning "$_ is expired"
    }
}
```